# How to read scriptfield Distance with v6.2?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using ElasticSearch version 5.5.1 and NEST 6.2.

I am calculating the distance using a ScriptField and including it in my search results. This solution used to work fine with an older version of NEST. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
  List<Item> results = new List<Item>();
  var rad = new Distance(radius, Nest.DistanceUnit.Kilometers);
  int c = 0;

  var geoResult = await _client.SearchAsync<Item>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(size)
    .StoredFields(sf => sf.Field("_source"))
    .ScriptFields(sf => sf
    .ScriptField("distance", sc => sc
    .Source("doc['location'].arcDistance(params.lat, params.lon) * 0.001")
    .Lang("painless")
    .Params(f => f.Add("lat", lat).Add("lon", lng))))
    .Query(q => q
      .Bool(b => b
        .Filter(filter => filter
        .GeoDistance(geo => geo
          .Field(f => f.Location)
          .Distance(rad).Location(lat, lng)
          .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)))))
    .Sort(sort => sort
      .GeoDistance(g => g
        .Field(f => f.Location)
        .Order(Nest.SortOrder.Ascending)
        .Points(new GeoLocation(lat, lng))
        .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc))));



  foreach (var item in geoResult.Documents)
  {
    Item item = new Item
    {
      Name = item.Name,
      Distance = (geoResult.Fields.ToArray())[c++].Values<Item, double>(p => p.Distance)[0],
      Latitude = item.Location.Latitude,
      Longitude = item.Location.Longitude
    };
    results.Add(item);
  }
  return results;
```